# In Kaliyug Is Three Out Of Every Four People Evil?

Tags: sin, evil, kali-yuga

I understand that we will face good and evil stuffs based on our karma. So everyone experiences will be different cause of karma, in life.

As a general rule though, will you guys say that three of every four people is evil in Kaliyug times ?

We are often taught that there are some bad folks but that “people are mostly good” in society. Have heard many say this so many times in just daily life, that people are “basically good”

But how can this be accurate in Kaliyug times ?

I think this idea messes us up and we end up thinking most people are ok and then we’re not on guard enough to save ourselves and others from evil types.

Wondering if Hinduism would say most folks are bad in Kaliyug.

Which seems kinda depressing but is very helpful to know, wish I’d known this earlier.

So that we’re cautious, and not getting messed up by evil persons in our career, in our socializing, travel, business dealings, money matters. Just normal life stuff.

Curious what will Hindu texts tell us on this topic so we can be as careful as possible and live ok life even though the yug is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong to say 3/4 people will be evil in kalyug .

watch this video about kalyug https://youtu.be/xTMzZwMwERY , your all doubts will be solved .

Comment: He says yug is all in the mind and no actual external yug phases exist, I have heard that many times. That yug is all mental and the debates about number of years is not accurate. I’m not sure about that, but I think there is something to it, in a partial meaning, and wonder if it can be both though ? Both that yug cycles happening in mind and also external time epochs and such can be there ? Because if look around at society these days, def seems like Kaliyug situation is happening

Comment: @devibhakt Although i have my doubts if yug is all in the mind, i have also heard from somewhere(Devibhagvata purana) that real Kalyug starts 10k years after end of Dwapara(which ended around 3076BC).5k more years to go :0 .So you could say we are in a transition period b/w Dwapara and Kali.Well acc to the video i think he(AP) just wants ppl to stop having misconceptions about yugas/too much focus on dates/timings and instead stress more on good conduct and action acc to ones dharma so that we can experience every moment as if we are Satya Yuga!

Comment: @Rāmachandra Yeah, I agree, & maybe it’s both a mind thing & also something that happens in reality. It’s weird but I find the idea of time cycles & universes being sorta the same, I find that kinda comforting. Like there’s not this huge big scary unknown, nothing like that, just chaturyug & kalp going on one after another. Then universe starts again & the same yug &  chaturyug &  kalp just continue. In parallel universes, looks the same, goes the same way. Just seems comforting somehow. No big mystery, just same stuff, no probs, just we can calm down and live ok, hehe 

Comment: Please give proper answer, just a video link isn't enough for the answers on stack exchange, you need to give some context as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).